# Сборка C# в рантайме. Зачем разделять string на части перед компиляцией?

Tags: c#, компиляция

Наткнулся на следующую [инструкцию](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime). На примере программы Привет мир, отправляемой в компилятор, показано как можно получить нужный PE-файл из строки. Но я никак не могу понять, зачем здесь разделили строку на отдельные, если конкретно тут нет никакого форматирования.

```cs
string code = @"
    using System;

    namespace First
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
            " +
                "Console.WriteLine(\"Hello, world!\");"
                + @"
            }
        }
    }
";
```

**Вопросы:** Зачем это нужно конкретно здесь? Это такая специфичность компиляции at Runtime? Может быть это всё просто заморочки автора?

Спасибо.

Comment: Где вы увидели разделение строки? У вас все идет в один `string`, без разницы как вы туда добавите текст, хоть `code += "значение"`, хоть `code = переменная`, хоть `code = "a" + "b"`, да даже можете через `StringBuilder` пойти, всеравно это превратиться в простой `string`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , дали ответ про кавычки в строках с буквальным идентификатором, думаю будет интересно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ :) да, гениальность ответа зашкаливает. :)

Comment: Вы зря такой длинный заголовок дали вопросу. Сделайте его как можно короче и понятнее.

Comment: @aepot, Краткость - сестра таланта. Поправите за меня? Я думаю у вас лучше получится. Спасибо.

Comment: Простите, а что в нем должно быть интересного? Я вам изначально сказал, что без разницы как в эту переменную попадает строка, главное, чтоб она там была. C# работает последовательно, сначала обрабатывает первая строка, потом вторая, потом третья и так далее и по этой причине тут ну прям вообще как угодно можно заполнить ее, хоть делайте добавление по букве на каждой строке) По этой причине, лично я вообще не вижу смысла в этом вопросе и ответе на него, ибо польза в чем? В том, чтоб объяснить вам, что "так захотел автор того поста"? Ну такое себе..

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Интересность как раз таки в том, что на, казалось бы, пустой вопрос можно найти адекватный ответ. Сайт для того и создан, чтобы развеять сомнения в каком либо вопросе, получить полезную информацию от других людей. У меня это получилось, хоть и Вам не понравился мой вопрос и ответ другого человека на него, Вам показалось это всё пустословным. Но Вы сейчас тоже занимаетесь чем-то подобным, а конкретно ответами про построение строки на этапе компиляции: простите, но ничего нового это мне не дало. Anyway, Холивар разводить не хочу, и надеюсь недопонимание ушло. Добра.

Comment: Вы неверно понимаете сайт. Это не форум, где вы приходите с любой болячкой и вам помогают, этот сайт является **базой вопросов и ответов** на них, где сообщество собирает ценное, делиться знаниями для будущих читателей. У вас вопрос "Почему автор разделил строку?", ответ "Ему так захотелось", вот где тут польза для будущих читателей? А не где. Вам это помогло, ок, я рад за вас, но сам вопрос мало подходит под формат сайта, увы, это не моя прихоть, это такая политика сайта, таковы правила. Так что, у меня нету к вам именно претензий, у меня их вообще нету, лишь говорю как обстоят дела.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Предлагаете удалить вопрос?

Comment: Вы в праве поступить так, как считаете нужным, я лишь говорю свое мнение и почему проголосовал за закрытие данного вопроса. Просто подумайте не со стороны "вот, это полезно мне", а со стороны "вот, это полезно другим", если считаете, что пользы нет, то я бы удалил, если считаете иначе, как и сказал ранее, ваше право.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не думаю, что здесь есть какой-либо в этом смысл, строку можно записать вот так, и ничего не изменится:

```cs
string code = @"
    using System;

    namespace First
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(""Hello, world!"");
            }
        }
    }
";
```

Быть может, автор поста просто не знал, как в [verbatim string literal](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) экранировать кавычки.

Comment: Я, наверное, излишне придирчив, но я просто думаю что это может быть сделано не просто так. Хотелось бы перед началом работы знать нюансы. Так значит-с, это просто автор так захотел?

Comment: @NasItaHighborne выглядит как заморочка автора, не более.